# PHP function to call JSON files

Tags: php, json, function

I am trying to make a basic PHP function in order to call json files repeatedly throughout the app. Every time I want to call a json file I use:

```
<? $site = json_decode(file_get_contents('views/partials/site.json')); ?>
```

Then I use echo to use data from json file like this:

```
<? echo $site[0]->title; ?>
```

But instead of repeating part one I want to write a function in the header and call it where I want to call a json file. After that i was planning to use the function like this:

```
$site = jsonCall('site');
```

by using the function below;

```
function jsonCall($jsonurl){
    // this is one line code. no difference from 3 lines below-> $jsonCalled = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage . 'views/partials/' . $jsonurl . '.json'));

    $url = $homepage . 'views/partials/' . $jsonurl . '.json';
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $jsonCalled = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
    echo $jsonCalled;
  };
```

but instead of what i want i got an array as a response from server. i think my function turns json file to an array and that way i can't call it properly.

anyone knows how to solve this simple issue? show me proper way to write this function so my code might look a bit easier to read. Thank you.

by changing echo in function with return and using `jsonCall('site')[0]->title;` everything worked fine.

Comment: Where is `$homepage` set at?  In the code above, it's undefined and may affect your ability to get the contents of the file.  In any case you should check that the file exists, and that the JSON is decoded properly, `file_exists` and `json_last_error`, `json_last_error_message`

Comment: $homepage is variable from main route file. it gets sites main folder url. i'm using it for simple file handling .

Comment: `$homepage is variable from main route file. it gets sites main folder url.` inside the scope of the function it probably doesn't exist, if it's set outside the function, you have to pass it in, define it as a constant, or dare I say `global`  I would go with one of the first 2

Comment: problem solved, issue was not about '$homepage' but something much easier. thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you are getting an array. Otherwise $site[0] (which is an array access at key zero) would not have worked.

From the PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
>   true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
>   respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Your appropriate PHP type is array.

The following should work:

```
jsonCall('site')[0]->title;
```

Therefore I can not see a problem with your code?

Comment: what about undefined `$homepage` variable?, don't you think it'a problem?

Comment: in the function instead of echo i used return and everything worked fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The server is responding with `Array` because that is how PHP represents an array when you are `echo`'ing it. Your function should be **return**ing the result.

Try:

```
function jsonCall($jsonurl){
    // this is one line code. no difference from 3 lines below-> $jsonCalled = json_decode(file_get_contents($homepage . 'views/partials/' . $jsonurl . '.json'));

    $url = $homepage . 'views/partials/' . $jsonurl . '.json';
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $jsonCalled = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed
    // echo $jsonCalled;
    return $jsonCalled; // <- this should work
};
```

Comment: with the code from first answer it worked thank you!